# How to display particular field in array of all objects

Tags: angular

I'm getting in console like this:

```
article:Array
0:Object
articleId: "WMCA880211"
competingInterests: "ff"
content: Array(3)
0: {title: "Abstract", content: "fdd", illustrations: Array(1)}
1: {title: "Introduction", content: "jj", illustrations: Array(1)}
2: {title: "Models", content: "kk", illustrations: Array(1)}
```

I want to display title of all objects in content array.

I tried like this, Here I am using two way data-binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of latestarticles">
<div class="row" *ngFor="let Content of article.content">
<input class="form-control" id="usr" name="content" [(ngModel)]="Content.title">
</div>
</div>
```

I'm getting output only "`Models`". I mean only last object of content array.
How can I get all objects of "`title`" in content Array?

Comment: Hm, so what's wrong with your code? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozk8ui

Comment: I am getting title from only last object. I need title of all objects

Comment: Have you checked stackblitz in previous comment?

Comment: @DanilGudz, I think OP has forgotten a crucial thing from the code, i.e that this is a form! Therefore, OP, please always remember to include all code necessary in question to see that your problem is showcased. Best is to even actually try the code before posting, like creating a Stackblitz to see yourself. Because the code you are presenting here is totally working as it should, but it doesn't when you add form tags, therefore the answer below is correct, even though person who answered assumed this.

Comment: And BTW, I also just "assume" that this is a form, since we don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name attribute should be unique.

try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of latestarticles">
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let Content of article.content; let i = index">
  <input class="form-control" id="usr" [name]="'content_'+i" [(ngModel)]="Content.title">
 </div>
</div>
```